# Unix socket gets stuck at accept()

Tags: c, server, unix-socket

I am writing a server that should wait for client to connect. After accessing the main loop server should "bounce" so long `accept()` does return a different value then -1. The problem is that the `accept()` method is blocking the execution instead of returning any value. What could be a reason for this if there is no invalid argument flag raised?

Bellow is a minimum reproducible example of my code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h> // unlink

#define MAX_LISTCLI 5

int main(void) {
  uint server_id, len;
  struct sockaddr_un server;

  if ((server_id = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(server.sun_path, "free_socket");
  if (unlink(server.sun_path) != -1)
    fprintf(stderr, "Server was NOT aboard correctly?\n");
  len = (strlen(server.sun_path) + sizeof(server.sun_family));
  if (bind(server_id, (struct sockaddr *)&server, len) == -1) {
    perror("Bind");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (listen(server_id, MAX_LISTCLI) == -1) {
    perror("Listen");
    exit(1);
  }
  _Bool done = 0;
  while (!done) {
    uint remote_id;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;

    len = sizeof(remote);
    // Bounce if connection was not obtained and wait for the client to connect
    printf("Connecting..\n");
    if ((remote_id =
         accept(server_id,
                (struct sockaddr *)&remote ,&len)) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Bounce..\n");
      continue;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Connected.\n");
    // Replay to the user..
    done = 1;
  }
  close(remote_id);
  close(server_id);
  unlink(server.sun_path);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with blocking on `accept()`, that's kind of the point of it to "wait for an incoming connection".  I note that your code is a minimal example, but, unless your program needs to do other things while waiting for the connection you should leave it as a blocking operation.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  How do you expect us to reproduce the problem if you post code that does not compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other post, you need to make your server socket nonblocking. You can do that by using [fcntl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fcntl).

```c
fcntl(server_id, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Then all of the calls that would normally block your socket will return a flag.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with the socket being **server_id** being blocking ([refer here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)).

> If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the
> socket is not marked as nonblocking, accept() blocks the caller
> until a connection is present.  If the socket is marked
> nonblocking and no pending connections are present on the queue,
> accept() fails with the error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

If you want the accept call to return immediately you would have to make the socket non blocking.

EDIT: I wouldn't recommend making it a non-blocking call as that would simply waste CPU cycles due to repeated execution of the while loop. The ideal way of dealing with this would block on the accept call and then use [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system call to spawn a new process.

Comment: That's what I am doing in the real application, this is just a minimal example for simplicity.

Comment: Or when it is blocked it will still accept the connection? I don't need to do this bouncing there?

Comment: All incoming connections to your server (from a client) are appended into a queue and when there is some connection to cater to in the queue accept call would return immediately with the socket file descriptor on the server side. However if there are no connection requests then the call would block until you get a connection, post which it would return.

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful information. But in my case I need to keep looping so server can check the `done` flag which is a parameter to `while`. I my real application this flag is a pointer used in the interface.